# Loss of data and tables after running php artisan migrate refresh & rollback

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Using Laravel, after running migrate, refresh & rollback commands, I lost all my tables and content from my MySQL database. Is there any option to get all my tables and data back?

First I had run:

```
php artisan migrate: refresh
```

And I lost all my data. I thought if I used the rollback command I could get my data back, so I then ran

```
php artisan migrate: rollback.
```

This caused me to lose all my tables too!

Comment: Pretty confusing question, do you mean that you ran `php artisan migrate:rollback` and `php artisan migrate:refresh`?

Comment: First I run: php artisan migrate:refresh I lost all data, I thought if I rollback I could get my data, so run php artisan migrate:rollback. Then I lost all my table too.

Comment: You clearly didn't know what rollback does. It reverts migrations not your commands. If you don't have a backup all your data is lost.

Comment: "Is there any option to get all my tables and data back"...restore a backup in MySQL. If you didn't have a job configured to automate mysql backups (at least daily) then...well it's a lesson for the future :-s

Comment: Okay thank you, I have a backup I'll use it. @ADyson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlucky my friend, it's a lesson to be learned from!

---

**Migrate | Refresh**

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Will revert all migrations for your application This will essentially drop all of the tables in your database before then re-running all of the `up()` portitions of your migrations.

---

**Migrate | Rollback**

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

This will look at the `migrations` table in your database and find all of the migrations run in the last batch (see the `batch` column on the `migrations` table). It will then run all of the `down()` methods to revert just those latest migrations.

---

**Conclusion**

Don't run `php artisan migrate:refresh` unless you have a database backup or don't care about losing the data (e.g. you are using seeders, etc)

---

**Addendum**

To re-import your database dump after a refresh, you can do something like this. However, ***this is not an ideal solution*** and I strongly suggest reading up on proper Database Seeding and Model Factories

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/seeding#writing-seeders

```
<?php

use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // Get the databse dump we wish to use
        $sql = base_path('database/dumps/your_database.sql');

        if ($sql) {
            // Remove foreign keys for now
            DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');

            // Now we seed using our database dump of
            DB::unprepared(file_get_contents($sql));

            // Enable foreign keys
            DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can run the migration command with the `--seed` option which will run your database seeders

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

Comment: Thank you. I am very new to laravel. This is my first project. Is it possible to use only the database from the backup?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. To answer your question, i'll need a little more information. What is in your database? Is it random seeded data? Or is it a copy of some production data? Or is it some test data you have added manually?

Comment: Mysql database. It is manually added test data. I replace the database file. Is it a good practice?

Comment: Ok, as a bit of homework, i'd strongly suggest looking into the documentation on database seeding and factories as it will help massively going forward. For now, i'll add a snippet to my answer you can use.

Comment: Try just removing it for now, it may well be that the `DB` alias is already available to things extending `Seeder`. That example comes from an old project running Laravel 5.1 so may well not be 100% compatible with newer versions of the framework. The principle behind it should still work though.

Comment: @Spholt Consider editing the Question adding a little explanation and formatting to the commands executed. It may be enough to reopen it in the queue.

Comment: @Scratte Good point! I've made some improvements to the original question to better explain what the OP had actually done