# I am creating user login management system with roles. I am getting error as, below when I run the command `$ php artisan db:seed`

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, foreign-keys, laravel-seeding

I am creating user login management system with roles. I am getting error as, below when I run the command `$ php artisan db:seed`

ErrorException

> file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzcomputer\database/dumps/your_database.sql): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

```
  at C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzcomputer\database\seeds\DatabaseSeeder.php:26
    22|             // Remove foreign keys for now
    23|             DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
    24| 
    25|             // Now we seed using our database dump of
  > 26|             DB::unprepared(file_get_contents($sql));
    27| 
    28|             // Enable foreign keys
    29|             DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
    30|
```

> 1   C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzcomputer\database\seeds\DatabaseSeeder.php:26
> file_get_contents("C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzcomputer\database/dumps/your_database.sql")

> 2   C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzcomputer\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:37
> DatabaseSeeder::run()

**DatabaseSeeder**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // Get the databse dump we wish to use
        $sql = base_path('database/dumps/your_database.sql');

        if ($sql) {
            // Remove foreign keys for now
            DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');

            // Now we seed using our database dump of
            DB::unprepared(file_get_contents($sql));

            // Enable foreign keys
            DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');


            $this->call(RolesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        }
    }
}
```

**UsersTableSeeder**

```
<?php

use App\User;
use App\Role;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
      User::truncatte();
      DB::table('role_user')->truncate();

      $adminRole = Role::where('name', 'admin')->first();
      $authorRole = Role::where('name', 'author')->first();
      $userRole = Role::where('name', 'user')->first();

      $admin = User::create([
        'name' => 'Admin User',
        'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
        'password' => Hash::make('password')
      ]);

      $author = User::create([
        'name' => 'Author User',
        'email' => 'author@author.com',
        'password' => Hash::make('password')
      ]);

     $user= User::create([
        'name' => 'Generic User',
        'email' => 'user@user.com',
        'password' => Hash::make('password')
      ]);

      $admin->roles()->attach($adminRole);
      $author->roles()->attach($authorRole);
      $user->roles()->attach($userRole);
    }
}
```

Comment: `DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');` move after seeders and change your seeder code to `$this->call([RolesTableSeeder::class, UsersTableSeeder::class ]);`

Comment: @xNoJustice  Then I am getting as :-
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`bizzcomputer`.`orders`, CONSTRAINT `orders_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `bizzcomputer`.`users` (`id`)) (SQL: truncate table `users`)

Comment: Haha, this looks like someone used code i posted the other day https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63557255/i-lost-all-my-tables-and-details-when-i-am-refresh-and-rollback-which-is-in-mysq/63557755#63557755

Answer (score 0):

```
//Remove foreign keys for now
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');

$this->call(RolesTableSeeder::class);
$this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);

// Enable foreign keys
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
```

Comment: If you have switched over to using seeders (a good choice btw), you may no longer need the two foreign key statements. Those were only there because of the unprepared statement in cases where pivot tables were inserted before both of their respective parent tables had been inserted.

Answer (score 0):

The error message pretty much says it all

> ErrorException
>
> file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzcomputer\database/dumps/your_database.sql): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

It is looking for a file called `your_database.sql` within the `database/dumps` directory within your repository.

Check that this file exists and that it has the correct permissions assigned to it